# SQL - How to use wildcard in LIKE as a normal character

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

if I have a column with some values that starts with "%" like this:

```
[ID]-----[VALUES]
1--------Amount
2--------Percentage
3--------%Amount
4--------%Percentage
```

how can I have only these two rows with a "select" query?:

```
[ID]-----[VALUES]
3--------%Amount
4--------%Percentage
```

I tried these queries but them don't work:

```
select * from TABLE where VALUES like '[%]%'
select * from TABLE where VALUES like '\%%'
```

I know that in Java, C and other languages, the backspace \ let you use a jolly character as a normal one like:

```
var s = "I called him and he sad: \"Hi, there!\"";
```

There is a similar character/function that do it in SQL?
All answers will be appreciated, thank you for reading the question!

Comment: `select * from TABLE where VALUES like '\%%'` works for me...

Comment: Perhaps you could do a replace first .....

EG 
WHERE Replace(Values, '%', '#') LIKE '#%'

Comment: There is a MySQL option NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES which may affect your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
select * from TABLE where VALUES like  '%[%]%'
```

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax.

Comment: missed the MySQL tag , was thinking SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Your query

```
select * from TABLE where VALUES like '\%%'
```

should work. The reason it doesn't is because you may have [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) enabled which would treat `\` as a literal character.

A way to avoid it is using `LIKE BINARY`

```
select * from TABLE where VALUES like binary '%'
```

or with an escape character (can be any character you choose) specification.

```
select * from TABLE where VALUES like '~%%' escape '~'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `ESCAPE` option on `LIKE`:

```
select *
from TABLE
where VALUES like '$%%' escape '$';
```

Anything following the escape character is treated as a regular character. However, the default is backslash (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)), so the version with backslash should do what you want.

Of course, you could also use a regular expression (although that has no hope of using an index).

Note:  `escape` is part of the answer standard so it should work in any database.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you'll need an escape character for this. In SQL you have to define the escape character.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE where VALUES like ESCAPE '!';`

I'm pretty sure you can use whatever character you want.

Here's a link to a microsoft explanation that goes into more detail.

[**Microsoft explanation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx#Pattern%20Matching%20with%20the%20ESCAPE%20Clause)

[**MySQL Explanation**](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/like.php)

Comment: Just realized this is MySQL, not SQL Server. However, the syntax is basically the same.